# Exact sequence $0\rightarrow H^i(A_{\bullet})\rightarrow\text{coker}f^{i-1}\rightarrow\text{im}f^i\rightarrow0$ - abstract nonsense proof?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I'm a little stuck on an exercise about cohomology in an abelian category. Given a complex $A^{\bullet}$, where $f^i:A^i\rightarrow A^{i+1}$ (so $f^{i+1}f^i=0$), let $H^i(A^{\bullet}):=\text{coker}(\text{im}f^i\rightarrow\ker f^{i+1})$. I want to show there is an exact sequence $0\rightarrow H^i(A^{\bullet})\rightarrow\text{coker}f^{i-1}\rightarrow\text{im}f^i\rightarrow0$. I'm pretty sure I know where the maps come from but i'm not sure how to show exactness.

Warning: I'm new to homological algebra so I currently use some notation in order to keep track of things (and because I'm lazy when it comes to variable names). Notation for a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$: the kernel of $f$ is $f_k:\ker f\rightarrow A$, and the cokernel $f^k:B\rightarrow\text{coker}f$. The image $\text{im f}\rightarrow B$ is thus $(f^k)_k$ but I simply denote it by $f_{im}$, and the map $A\rightarrow\text{im} f$ by $\tilde{f}$ (so $f=f_{im}\tilde{f})$.

In detail + my current progress: we have this [commutative diagram](https://q.uiver.app/?q=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). Where these maps came from: the ones with an $f$ in their labels are all apparent  (hopefully), and those with mono/epi arrow notation should also be mono/epi for clear or at least well-known reasons.

The map $g$ comes from the fact that $0=f^if^{i-1}=f^i(f^{i-1})_{im}\widetilde{f^{i-1}}$, so since $\widetilde{f^{i-1}}$ is epi, $f^i(f^{i-1})_{im}=0$ and thus $(f^{i-1})_{im}$ factors uniquely through $(f^i)_k$. Furthermore, $g$ is mono because $(f^i)_kg$ is (so if $g\alpha=0$ then $(f^i)_kg\alpha=0\Rightarrow\alpha=0$). The map $g^k$ is by definition the cokernel of $g$ and is epi for that reason.

Similarly, $0=f^if^{i-1}=(f^i)_{im}\widetilde{f^i}f^{i-1}$ and $(f^i)_{im}$ is mono, so $\widetilde{f^i}f^{i-1}=0$. Hence $\widetilde{f^i}$ factors uniquely through $(f^{i-1})^k$ - this is where $h$ comes from. And since $\widetilde{f^i}=h(f^{i-1})^k$ is epi, $h$ must be as well, which gives me the right side of the desired short exact sequence.

The real mystery lies with the morphism $H^i(A^{\bullet})\rightarrow\text{coker}f^{i-1}$. I constructed this morphism by noticing $0=(f^{i-1})^kf^{i-1}=(f^{i-1})^k(f^i)_kg\widetilde{f^{i-1}}$, so since $\widetilde{f^{i-1}}$ is epi, $(f^{i-1})^k(f^i)_kg=0$, so $(f^{i-1})^k(f^i)_k$ must factor through $g^k$, so we get $h'$.

At this point the duality/symmetry between the top left and bottom right side of the diagram is clear to me (indeed it looks as if $H^i(A^{\bullet})$ could also have been defined by $\ker(\text{coker}f^{i-1}\rightarrow\text{im}f^i)$ - is this right?) but I'm having trouble proving this symmetry exists. I can't even show $H^i(A^{\bullet})\rightarrow\text{coker}f^{i-1}$ is mono, let alone a kernel of $h$. One thing I can show is $hh'=0$: since $(f^i)_{im}hh'g^k=f^i(f^i)_k=0$, and since $g^k$ and $(f^i)_{im}$ are epi and mono respectively, we have $hh'=0$. I also rather suspect $h'g^k$ is the unique decomposition of $(f^{i-1})^k(f^i)_k$ through its image, but this is just an intuitive guess.

Now I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909745/constructing-short-exact-sequence-from-complex) but the answer appears to be appealing to the snake lemma. This is the second sequence in exercise 1.6.A on page 51 of Ravi Vakil's [notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), and while the snake lemma is mentioned before this exercise, it is neither stated nor proven, so I'm wondering if there's a way to do without it. I can do an element chase, but I'm also wondering if there's an abstract nonsense way to finish the construction I've given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the exact sequence is describing cohomology as a kernel instead of a cokernel. That is, you have a map
$f^j : A^j \longrightarrow A^{j+1}$
but since the image of $f^{j-1}$ is in the kernel of this map, you can consider

$$\bar f^j : A^j/\mathrm{Im}(f^{j-1}) = \mathrm{Coker}(f^{j-1}) \longrightarrow A^{j+1}$$

The induced map  $\bar f^j : A^j/\mathrm{Im}(f^{j-1}) = \mathrm{Coker}(f^{j-1}) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Im}(f^j)$ is surjective. Moreover, the kernel of $\bar f^j$ is $\mathrm{Ker}(f^j)/\mathrm{Im}(f^{j-1})= H^j(A)$, giving the usual short exact sequence

$$0 \longrightarrow H^j(A)  \longrightarrow   \mathrm{Coker}(f^{j-1}) 
  \longrightarrow  \mathrm{Im}(f^j)   \longrightarrow  0$$

of the form $0\to \mathrm{Ker}(\alpha) \to A \to \mathrm{Im}(\alpha)\to 0$ for a morphism $\alpha : A\to B$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow: Why is the kernel of $\text{coker}f^{j-1}\rightarrow A^{j+1}$ the map $H^j(A)\rightarrow\text{coker}f^{j-1}$? This would definitely solve the problem, but I don't see how it follows from the other information.

Comment: @P-addict Can you prove this in Abelian groups? Essentially, you just need to show that if $K\to A$ is the kernel of some map $A\to B$ and $L\to K$ is mono then the kernel of $A/L\to B$ is $K/L$. You just need to use two universal properties, but note that $K/L \to A/L$ is at least mono.

Comment: Sorry for my absence - I see it now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another proof, although it relies on a few results. Using the notation from the diagram in the question, we show two things:

- $h$ is the cokernel of $h’$
- $h’$ is mono

Then $h’$ is the kernel of $h$ and its own image since monos are the kernels of their cokernels in abelian categories, so we have the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow H^i(A^{\bullet})\rightarrow\text{coker}f^{i-1}\rightarrow\text{im}f^i\rightarrow0$.

To show the first point, suppose $x:\text{coker}f^{i-1}\rightarrow X$ such that $xh’=0$. Then $x(f^{i-1})^k(f^i)_k=xh’g^k=0$, and since $A^i\rightarrow\text{im}f^i$ is the coimage of $f^i$, it is the cokernel of $(f^i)_k$, so $x(f^{i-1})^k$ factors uniquely through $\widetilde{f^i}$, i.e. there is a unique morphism $y:\text{im}f^i\rightarrow X$ such that $x(f^{i-1})^k=y\widetilde{f^i}=yh(f^{i-1})^k$. Since $(f^{i-1})^k$ is epi, $x=yh$ with $y$ unique. Thus $h$ is the cokernel of $h'$.

Finally, to show $h'$ is mono, we can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348250/quotients-preserve-monomorphisms-in-abelian-categories) result, with $A=\text{im}f^{i-1}$, $B=\ker f^i$, and $C=A^i$.